# Defining a Map[Int, String] with long strings as right value

Tags: scala

I'm trying to use a concatenation of string litterals
as value in a `Map[Int, String]` definition:

```
scala> val m: Map[Int, String] = Map(1 -> "a" + "b")
```

but I get the following error from `sbt console`

```
<console>:7: error: type mismatch;
 found   : String
 required: (Int, String)
       val m: Map[Int, String] = Map(1 -> "a" + "b")
```

The reason I would want to do such a thing is because I want to define maps from an id to some code like so:

```
Map(1 -> s"""SELECT year, COUNT(*) FROM""" + 
         s"""  (SELECT id, YEAR(pb_date) AS year  FROM Publications) AS Res1""" +
         s"""GROUP BY year;""")
```

without having to define a string for each of the code snippets present as Map right value.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Just as an aside, a lot of people consider SQL string construction to be poor form. If you want to map an id to a function, you can do just that: functions are values in Scala so you can store them in your map like [this](http://pastebin.com/ZE4ELrca)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are just missing some parentheses:

```
scala> val m: Map[Int, String] = Map(1 -> ("a" + "b"))
m: Map[Int,String] = Map(1 -> ab)
```

The reason why you are getting that error specifically is because `->` takes precedence over `+`, meaning that you actually get `(1 -> "a") + b`, as you can see below:

```
scala> 1 -> "a" + "b"
res4: String = (1,a)b
```

Comment: "probably"? Definitively!

Comment: Ah yeah, now that I think about it, that error makes perfect sense